# Show SliderInput only when inserting inputFile in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

You could help me with the following question: first of all, the code is executable to make it easier. I have a tabPanel with two Radiobuttons and 1 SliderInput. However, I would like to show the SliderInput, as well as the options for ""Satisfied" only when I insert the file via inputFile.
I believe to do this is using the conditionalPanel function, but I'm not sure.

Can you help me??

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)

#database
df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35), Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, 
                                                                                                                                                 + -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     + -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6), Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          + 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))

function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){

  if (Filter1==2){
    Q1<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.25)) 
    Q3<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.75))
    L<-Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)
    S<-Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1)
    df_1<-subset(df,Waste>L[1]) 
    df<-subset(df_1,Waste<S[1])
  }

  #cluster
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 


  #Number of clusters
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #Localization
  center_mass<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center_mass[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                       weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  center_mass<-cbind(center_mass,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 

  #Coverage
  coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),center_mass[i,])[,2:1])
    coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
  coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage_meters","cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential_Waste_m3","cluster")

  #Output table
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage, sum_waste))
  data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Properties)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage_meters + Potential_Waste_m3, data_table[,c(1,7,6,2)], toString)

  #Scatter Plot
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
  df1<-as.data.frame(center_mass)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")
  g<-ggplot(data=df,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,  color=factor(clusters))) + geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4)
  Centro_View<- g +  geom_text(data=df, mapping=aes(x=eval(Longitude), y=eval(Latitude), label=Waste), size=3, hjust=-0.1)+ geom_point(data=df1, mapping=aes(Longitude, Latitude), color= "green", size=4) + geom_text(data=df1, mapping = aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, label = 1:k), color = "black", size = 4)
  plotGD<-print(Centro_View + ggtitle("Scatter Plot") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))

  return(list(
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 

             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("data", h3("Import excel")), 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          radioButtons("filter1", h3("Select properties"),
                                       choices = list("All properties" = 1, 
                                                      "Exclude properties" = 2),
                                       selected = 1),

                          radioButtons("filter2", h3("Select properties"),
                                       choices = list("All properties" = 1, 
                                                      "Exclude properties" = 2),
                                       selected = 1),
                          tags$hr(),
                          tags$b(h3("Satisfied?")),
                          tags$b(h5("(a) Choose other filters")),
                          tags$b(h5("(b) Choose clusters")),  
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 8, value = 5),
                          tags$hr(),
                          actionButton("reset", "Reset")
                        ),

                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))

                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  v <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$data, {
    v$df <- read_excel(input$data$datapath)
  })


  Modelcl<-reactive({if (!is.null(v$df)) {
    function.cl(v$df,input$Slider,1,1)
  }
  })


  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[2]]
  })

  observeEvent(input$Slider,{
    updateSelectInput(session,'select',
                      choices=unique(df[df==input$Slider]))
  }) 

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do, in `server`:

```
  output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
    !is.null(input$data)
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
```

Then in `ui`, use a `conditionalPanel`:

```
conditionalPanel(
  "output.fileUploaded == true",
  ......
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, you can show me where I put this information in my code. An error occurred while entering the code in the "ui". If you could insert it in my code, I would appreciate it.